# how can I make a generic table component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am new in Typescript and want to ask you how can I make generic data in a table ?

I got this error on line useTable({ at data

```
Type 'T[]' is not assignable to type 'readonly object[]'.
  Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'object'
```

```
import { Price_Type } from "~/data/db_action.server";
import { useTable } from 'react-table';

export interface ITable<T> {
  columns: any;
  data: T[];
  onClick: (price_id: string) => void;
}

export default function Table<T>({
  columns,
  data,
  onClick
}: ITable<T>) {
  const {
    getTableProps, // table props from react-table
    getTableBodyProps, // table body props from react-table
    headerGroups, // headerGroups, if your table has groupings
    rows, // rows for the table based on the data passed
    prepareRow // Prepare the row (this function needs to be called for each row before getting the row props)
  } = useTable({
    columns,
    data
  });
  return (
    <table {...getTableProps()}>
      <thead>
        {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
          <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
            {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
              <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render("Header")}</th>
            ))}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </thead>
      <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
        {rows.map((row, i) => {
          prepareRow(row);
          return (
            <tr className="transition" {...row.getRowProps()} onClick={() => row.original?.id && onClick(row.original.id)}>
              {row.cells.map(cell => {
                return <td className="transition" {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render("Cell")}</td>;
              })}
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  )
}
```

i am very thankful for your help and IDK what I am doing wrong, I do not want to make every time a new component for a table.

Comment: You can start with `T extends object`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're getting the error is because you're trying to assign a generic array of type `T[]` to a property that expects  an array of objects `object[]` in the `useTable` hook.

Instead you'd use something like this:

```
import { useTable } from 'react-table';

export interface ITable<T extends object> {
  columns: any;
  data: T[];
  onClick: (price_id: string) => void;
}

export default function Table<T extends object>({
  columns,
  data,
  onClick
}: ITable<T>) {
  const {
    getTableProps, // table props from react-table
    getTableBodyProps, // table body props from react-table
    headerGroups, // headerGroups, if your table has groupings
    rows, // rows for the table based on the data passed
    prepareRow // Prepare the row (this function needs to be called for each row before getting the row props)
  } = useTable({
    columns,
    data
  });

  return (
    <table {...getTableProps()}>
      <thead>
        {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
          <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
            {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
              <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render("Header")}</th>
            ))}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </thead>
      <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
        {rows.map((row, i) => {
          prepareRow(row);
          return (
            <tr className="transition" {...row.getRowProps()} onClick={() => row.original?.id && onClick(row.original.id)}>
              {row.cells.map(cell => {
                return <td className="transition" {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render("Cell")}</td>;
              })}
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  )
}
```